# Some kernel ARM code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, system-calls

I was reading through some ARM kernel sources till I stumbled upon the following function :-

```
314 #define __get_user_asm_byte(x, addr, err)                       \
315         __asm__ __volatile__(                                   \
316         "1:     " TUSER(ldrb) " %1,[%2],#0\n"                   \
317         "2:\n"                                                  \
318         "       .pushsection .fixup,\"ax\"\n"                   \
319         "       .align  2\n"                                    \
320         "3:     mov     %0, %3\n"                               \
321         "       mov     %1, #0\n"                               \
322         "       b       2b\n"                                   \
323         "       .popsection\n"                                  \
324         "       .pushsection __ex_table,\"a\"\n"                \
325         "       .align  3\n"                                    \
326         "       .long   1b, 3b\n"                               \
327         "       .popsection"                                    \
328         : "+r" (err), "=&r" (x)                                 \
329         : "r" (addr), "i" (-EFAULT)                             \
330         : "cc")
```

The calling context seems is as follows :-

```
299 #define __get_user_err(x, ptr, err)                                     \
300 do {                                                                    \
301         unsigned long __gu_addr = (unsigned long)(ptr);                 \
302         unsigned long __gu_val;                                         \
303         __chk_user_ptr(ptr);                                            \
304         might_fault();                                                  \
305         switch (sizeof(*(ptr))) {                                       \
306         case 1: __get_user_asm_byte(__gu_val, __gu_addr, err);  break;  \
```

Now I have a few doubts I'd like to clear about the ARM assembly above.

1. What is the function `__get_user_asm_byte` doing? I can see that r3 is copied into r0 and that the value 0 is moved into r1. After that does it branches to the offset 0x2b?
2. What is the function trying to do? What does the `"+r" (err), "=&r" (x)` from line 328 onward mean?
3. What is a .pushsection and a .popsection?
4. Why does ARM assembly thats written for the kernel so different syntactically(what's the assembler used? Why are there `%<regno>` instead of `r<regno>`?)

Comment: As for 4. — it is an assembly syntax that you can find if you tell to GCC to compile but not assemble *( `-S` option).* I.e. the assembler app is GAS.

Comment: `%0` is not `r0`. `2b` is not `0x2b`. Read the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: @CL. Thanks that helps! If you could add that in as an answer I could accept that.

Answer (score 4):

First, as comments have noted, the syntax is standard gcc inline assembly syntax (the `+r`, `=&r`, `%<arg>` parts).

The rest is kernel magic designed to handle page faults. The point of get_user_asm_byte is to pull a byte from user-space. However, in pulling data from user-space, two special situations need to be accommodated:

1. A perfectly legitimate user-space address that is simply not present at the moment (i.e. usually because it's paged out)
2. An illegal user-space address.

Either could cause a page fault. For (1), the desired behavior is to restore the user page (read it back in from swap space or whatever), then re-execute the load instruction, resulting in eventual success; for (2), the desired behavior is to fail the operation without retrying, returning an `EFAULT` error to the caller.

Without special handling, the normal behavior of a page fault in kernel mode is an "Oops". The special sections coordinate with the page fault handling code and make it possible to recover correctly. If you want to understand the details of how this works, search for `__ex_table` in the kernel source.

Also, checkout kernel doc at: [Documentation/x86/exception-tables.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/x86/exception-tables.txt)

The only ARM specific item is to use either `ldrt` or MMU domains; this is conditional in [domain.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/domain.h#n85).  Modern ARM CPUs support domains.  The *translated* load/store variants apply a user mode access for older CPUs.